# Chaining promises with action reducers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise

I have a method which is firing two http requests to API to get the data.

```
getServerDetails(this.props.match.params.id) //1
            .then(res => {
                this.props.getServerDetailsAction({ success: true, data: res.data })

                if (!_.isEmpty(res.data)) {
                    return getServerScomAlerts(res.data.ServerName) //2
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => { //3
                this.props.getServerDetailsAction({ success: false, error: err })
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (!_.isEmpty(res)) {
                    this.props.getServerScomAlertsAction({ success: true, data: res.data })
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => { //4
                this.props.getServerScomAlertsAction({ success: false, error: err })
            })
```

`getServerDetails (1)` and `getServerScomAlerts (2)` methods are returning promises. `getServerScomAlerts (2)` is dependent on the result of `getServerDetails (1)`

The problem is that if error occurs in `getServerScomAlerts (2)` the first catch block `(3)` is executed. Is there a way how to get the data from the first method `(1)` (***without accessing store***) and at the same time jump to the corresponding catch block `(4)` if the error occurs?

Comment: You could consider using `async/await` with traditional `try {} catch {}` blocks for more control over this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might give you an idea how to achieve your goal. Instead of having nested then, you can use async/await and it waits for the result of each call before proceeding to the next:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    myFunc: (param1, param2) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        try {
            const response1 = await fetch(param1);
            const data1 = await response.json();

            const response2 = await fetch(param2);
            const data2 = await response2.json();

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really interesting with your problem since you want to do multiple actions which are slightly different from each other only :). I would rewrite as following

```
const getServerScomAlertsAction = (success, props) => (res) => {
  success = success && !_.isEmpty(res);
  props.getServerScomAlertsAction(success ? { success, data: res.data } : { success, error: res });
};
const getServerDetailsAction = (success, props) => (res) => {
  props
    .getServerDetailsAction(success ? { success, data: res.data } : { success, error: res })
    .then(getServerScomAlertsAction(true, props))
    .catch(getServerScomAlertsAction(false, props));
};

getServerDetails(this.props.match.params.id)
  .then(getServerDetailsAction(true, this.props))
  .catch(getServerDetailsAction(false, this.props));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for `.finally()` method, currently in draft specification according to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally). It allows you to remove duplication logic, by running the method after the promise is resolved or rejected.

As shown in the MDN example:

```
let isLoading = true;

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
  })
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); /* this line can also throw, e.g. when console = {} */ })
  .finally(function() { isLoading = false; });
```

If you want to use the feature right now, you can consider using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) for your promise implimentation, which in some cases is faster, and should be easy to upgrade from as the method is standarized